# when i am edit files,Image file Not uploading his target path

Tags: php, html, image, forms

I have developed small application with small form,Name and image.

- When i am fill the form and click on submit button these form values are stored in database(Name and image path stored in database),and image stored in target folder.
- Here is a problem,when i am click on form edit button,edited Name its successfully edited and stored in database.
- But when i am browse a image file it's not storing his path into database and image into target folder.

It shows old image path and Image in DB and form.

Here is code.
**Form.html**

```
<html>
<form  name="files" onsubmit="return formValidator()" action="update.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label  class="form_label_name">Name<span class="red">*</span>:</label>
         <input name="name" type="text" maxlength="32" class="form_input_name" id="form_name" required value="<?php {echo $row['name'];} ?>">

       <label  class="form_label_image">Grid Image:</label>
       <img id="imagetd" class="gridimage" src="<?php {echo $row['thumbnailimage'];} ?>" onclick="getImagePathFromDialog()" />
       <label>Click on the image to change the Image</label> 
       <input type="file" id="imageBrowser" name="imageBrowser" onchange="readURL(this);" style="visibility:hidden;"  />

    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" class="editfile_save">

</html>
```

**Edit Form:-**

[image]

**update.php:-**

```
<?php 
global $nodeid;
global $parentnodeid;
global $user;
global $file_type;

$file_type=$_GET['type'];
$userid=$user->uid;

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'xxx';
$dbpass = 'yyy';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$sqlappidquery = "SELECT appid FROM app WHERE userid=$userid ";
$appidqueryrows = db_query($sqlappidquery, array());
foreach ($appidqueryrows as $appidrow) {
$app_id=$appidrow->appid;
}
if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
   $name = addslashes ($_POST['name']);
   $summary = addslashes ($_POST['summary']);
   $url= addslashes ($_POST['urlPath']);
}
else
{
   $name =  $_POST['name'];
   $summary =  $_POST['summary'];
   $url =  $_POST['urlPath'];
}
$target_path = "/sites/default/files/content_images/";
$imagepath=basename( $_FILES['imageBrowser']['name']);
$ext = explode("/", $_FILES['imageBrowser']['type']);
if($ext[0] == 'image')
{
if(empty($imagepath))
{
$target_path =$row['thumbnailimage'];
}
else
{
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['imageBrowser']['name']);
}
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageBrowser']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
}
else
{
$target_path =$row['thumbnailimage'];
}
?>
```

Can any one help me on this problem.

Comment: your code even working at all ? i dont think  it should work at all, because you are using deprecated MySQL_*  api  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189

Comment: It's working fine,form values are stored when i am update the form,but image is not displaying and not stored in folder also.

Comment: @User add encryption type in form <form name="' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

Comment: why are you using backward php version ? because it should not work after php5.4

Comment: @bablu i have done that work and tested,now image path stored in database,but image is not stored in folder

Comment: this is a old application.

Comment: @User your if loop says that if($_FILES["imageBrowser"]["type"] == 'image') but it should be if($_FILES["imageBrowser"]["type"] == 'image/jpeg')

Comment: @bablu i have updated if loop,can you look that once.

Comment: @User Still image not saving into target folder? Have you checked folde permission

Comment: yes,permissions also given,i am doing this work in local system.

Comment: what is $row['thumbnailimage']?

Comment: Image thumbnail value /sites/default/files/content_images/xyz.jpg

Comment: Have you created separate JS methods for "return formValidator()"?

Comment: yes,created seperate function for validation

Answer (score 0):

```
<form  name="files" onsubmit="return formValidator()" action="update.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and change your select query like below

```
$sqlappidquery = "SELECT appid FROM app WHERE userid='".$userid."' ";
```

user form tag like this

Comment: Image is not uploading his target folder.

Comment: This time path also updated in database,but image is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

I think u forgot to add `enctype="multipart/formdata"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

and write update code

```
 UPDATE appid SET image='$image' WHERE id='$id';
```

Comment: There is no problem with path in database,path is storing,but image not displaing.